# How is 'Chanda' (Intention) related to 'Tanha' (Desire)?

Tags: karma, desire

How is ['Chanda' (Intention)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chanda_(Buddhism))  related to ['Tanha' (Desire)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ta%E1%B9%87h%C4%81)?

I often hear that Karma is determined by intention. I want to know how they are all related. What comes first? What gets abandoned in meditation and Nirvana?

I know of a YouTuber who claims to have gotten Nirvana, but he said after some time he had to train himself to purposefully generate an intention to talk and explain things to other people. So did he also have a prior desire to help other people? How this three work for Enlightened people and seekers?

Answer (score 1):

`Chanda` is a reason for `Tanha`. `Ignorance (Avidya)` is the cause for `Chanda` means it's the cause for `Tanha`. Then `Tanha` causes to increases the `Chanda`'s density towards something.

`Nirvana` is understanding `Chanda` towards something is a useless thing. As nothing in this world is going to satisfy the `intention (Chanda)` the living beings have. That's why no one can reach ultimate satisfaction. If someone reaches ultimate satisfaction there's nothing he/she needs to do further as he/she is already satisfied. The person who doesn't want anything (as he is ultimately satisfied) is the person who obtained `Nirvana`.

Someone who obtained `Nirvana` has limitless `metta (loving / kindness)` towards the living beans. Due to that reason, they may try to share the path to `Nirvana` with others.

Answer (score 0):

> I often hear that Karma is determined by intention. I want to know how they are all related. What comes first? What gets abandoned in meditation and Nirvana?

Intention is kamma. It is not the only thing that is thought of as kamma. Intending one perceives, intending one conceives.

Origin of kamma is contact.

Contact is one end, origin of contact is the other end, cessation of contact is the middle and craving is the seamstress because it weaves one to this or that state of existence which is discerned in dependence on contact.